# Rest API call to fetch data from multiple API providers in very minimal time : Example websites like makemytrip

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, rest

Websites like makemytrip fetches flight booking details from different airlines api providers like jetairways, indigo and so on.

when we visit there home page we see flight booking details of various airlines.

Since this information cant be cached. 
How will they make rest calls to all those api providers assuming there can be 10k - 20k of airlines api providers to display data on there home/search page.

**1) Will they make concurrent calls to all those api providers to fetch data, whenever we visit there home/search page ?**

But considering number of threads in the pool this would take time to fetch data and map them in the response object, which will cause delay in page load time.

**2) If we think of storing these data in search engines like elastic search, this even wont help as the data is not latest one.**

Even if we think of having a **"scheduler job"** which makes rest calls to api providers to get latest data every 5 minutes and store in Elastic search. This would make display stale data in that 5 minutes of span time.

Answer (score 1):

You might get a certain price in the first query and later when you try to purchase the ticket, often the prices have gone up. So I would say a mix of everything is used in aggregation sites.

APIs are sold commercially by providers and they carry SLAs. So you can have a robust scalable infrastructure on cloud (say AWS) and yours APIs fetch data from a fast highly available data source - and you can always meet millisecond SLAs every single time. An AWS Lambda function always runs as fast as possible regardless of the load.

So, I don't see a problem concurrently accessing APIs, aggregating the results and displaying it. Also, I don't see a problem applying some level of caching (either at the aggregator side or at the provider side) especially for slow APIs.

Client side cache can be updated by push notification instead of pull. So whenever there's an update in server data, the same is replicated at the client side. This avoids the need for running schedulers (check AWS SNS).

Your question is mainly focusing on tech and not business.

Online travel agencies (OTAs), such as Expedia, get most of their flight content through Global Distribution Systems (e.g., Sabre, Amadeus). Most airlines currently have agreed to make available their full content in the GDSs. The OTAs then make money from payments from airlines, GDSs and potentially (although less and less commonly) from the traveler. Air content is usually sold through an agency model, so the OTA does not take inventory risk on it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are some solutions to this problem. It depends on the datas and variables. I will explain some possible results but of course not all.
In your case the second option is less possible because you have many variables in a fly, like date and location, return or not and so on. But in other similar problems it could be useful.

### 1 - Concurrent calls

A first possibility is to make concurrent calls to all the given APIs, and show the results then.
If the longer request lasts 5 seconds, all the requests are sent at the same time and 5 seconds later you have the response.
Imagine: you load the page and there is no results, there is a loader or something like that. During the loader loading, an AJAX request to their servers is getting the results taken from all the websites.
Once all the results loaded they are displayed on the page.

### 2 - Compiling datas

An other possiblity is to use the same technique as search engines, loads datas and compile them.
Every 5 minutes (for example) a request is sent to every website and stored into a database. So when you are asking for the page, the datas are already in the database.

This option is difficult to realize for websites like MakeMyTrip because there are many location, many dates, and it's impossible to load all the datas.